How can I restore my applications and data backed up to a micro SD card to a properly formatted drive?
I backed up the entire system into a 1 TB micro SD card. At the time, I was using an APFS-formatted HDD. Then I read that APFS was not the best format for old Macs like mine, so I thought why not reinstall macOS High Sierra from a USB installer on an Extended Journaled formatted drive to keep everything the right way and restore the Time Machine backup from the Migration Assistant? What are the odds?
Well, it didn't work. Now all applications restored are grayed and say I can't open them, because they are not supported for this type of Mac. Not only that, no documents have appeared where they belong, none, not one, not on the desktop, nothing.
I selected all the options to restore the full 220 GB contents and I only see gray restored apps. So, I decided to reinstall the OS on an APFS drive again and got the same results, over and over, and countless hours of waiting lost.
Another thing, the backup disk takes about 10 minutes to mount in Disk Utility and finally shows the icon on the desktop. I can open the disk look at the files and drag them onto the desktop, but it won't let me open any of them. No one. Plus, when I download, let's say Firefox browser from the internet, it won't install either, nor any other program.
So, I am a regular user, I don't understand command prompts or Terminal operations, but I am very meticulous when following instructions when I am being helped.
I am running macOS High Sierra on a 2009 iMac.

what was the format of the SD card? It's possible some attributes / file system flags were not preserved if you used a cross platform disk format. Best bet is to use HFS+ or APFS on the SD card
